# FOS User bundle confirm link forces you to login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've been asked to add a confirmation email into a CRM, whereupon a user will sign up then be sent an email with a link to confirm in order to enable their account. However, whenever the link is clicked it instantly redirects to the login page, which is useless since they have not confirmed it. I've tried to exclude it in the `security.yml` file, but thus far no luck.

I've tried:

```
- { path: ^/register/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

- { path: ^/confirm/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

- { path: ^/register/confirm/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But none of these seem to work.

As requested, the routing file for FOS registration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_user_registration_register" path="/" methods="GET POST">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:register</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_registration_check_email" path="/check-email" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_registration_confirm" path="/confirm/{token}" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirm</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_registration_confirmed" path="/confirmed" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirmed</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

FOS User config:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template:   emails/registration.html.twig
            from_email:
                address:        noreply@siteemail.co.uk
                sender_name:    #sender name here#
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        noreply@siteemail.co.uk
                sender_name:    #sender name here#
            template: emails/password_reset.html.twig
```

Symfony 3.1 / FOS User Bundle 2.0
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show the `app/config/routing.yml` file?

Comment: Also, please edit you question and add: 1. Versions of symfony and fosUser. 2. Add app/config/config.yml  - fos_user parameters

Comment: Have added. I assumed you meant the routing file for FOS? My own routing file is very long and has no reference to FOS, except for linking to the routing resource for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO because the confirm route is `path="/confirm/{token}"` then you have to allow the `^/(confirm/){1}.+` path to be athenticated anonymously in the security.yml, because user is not authenticated yet during the confirmation.

So edit the **security.yml** to: `- { path: '^/(confirm/){1}.+', role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Also check the url in the registration email - it should point to `example.com/confirmation/???`

Answer (score 1):

Check your security.yml 
This configuration have to work!

```
## app/config/security.yml

## ...

firewalls:
    # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
    # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            # redirect to "/login" path if you aren't an admin
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            #csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            #always_use_default_target_path: true
            #default_target_path: homepage
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800
            domain: ".%domain_name%"
            always_remember_me: true
        anonymous: true
        logout:
          path: fos_user_security_logout
```

Also in the same security.yml you can add this lines:

```
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

This configuration should work. 
Also there are another approach with determined host:

```
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/logout$,        host: ^%domain_name%$,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$,         host: ^%domain_name%$,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register,       host: ^%domain_name%$,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting,      host: ^%domain_name%$,          roles: ROLE_USER }
```

`%domain_name%` - is your domain name i.e. example.com, which you should declare in `app/config/parameters.yml`

Comment: This is pretty much what my security file looks like. I can register, login, reset password but just the confirmation link for registration doesn't work correctly. To be honest I thought it was linked from register, like `register/confirm/{token}` but maybe I'm wrong?